Faster voxelization with inverse indices
I am using the following piece of code to get a voxelized point cloud with inverse indices so that I can compute the e.g. mask on the downsampled point cloud and then apply it on the original point cloud by getting the original points through inverse indices.
def voxelize(points, voxel_size):
    voxel_indices = np.floor(points / voxel_size).astype(np.int32)
    unique_voxel_indices, inverse_indices = np.unique(
        voxel_indices, axis=0, return_inverse=True
    )
    voxel_centers = (unique_voxel_indices + 0.5) * voxel_size
    return voxel_indices, unique_voxel_indices, voxel_centers, inverse_indices

However, this code is becoming a bottleneck for me as it is executed thousands of times.
I find similar questions to speed up this but without the inverse indices. Numba also does not have this version of np.unique implemented. Is there any method I am missing that is significantly faster but also provides the indices calculation?

You can probably do what you need without np.unique.
voxel_indices = np.floor(points / voxel_size) maps all points to the coordinate of the corner of the corresponding voxel in the downsampled grid. We have voxel_indices.shape == (N, 3) for N points.
As the variable name voxel_indices suggests, this array contains for each point its index in the downsampled voxel grid. This holds assuming that you defined your downsampled voxel grid such that the voxel with corner coordinates [i,j,k] in downsampled-space corresponds to corner coordinates [i*voxel_size, j*voxel_size, k*voxel_size] in points-space. (You can anyway achieve this easily by construction by shifting the point cloud appropriately with respect to the origin).
You then define a mask on the downsampled voxel grid. Let's call it mask_downsampled. It has shape (I,J,K), and the property that mask_downsampled[i,j,k] == True if and only if the downsampled voxel with corner coordinates [i,j,k] should be masked out.
You can apply the mask to your original points as follows:
# get the mask for each point - shape (N, 3)
mask = mask_downsampled[voxel_indices[:, 0], voxel_indices[:, 1], voxel_indices[:, 2]]

# keep all points that are not masked out
unmasked_points = points[~mask]


Thanks for answer. However, you write that shape of points is (N, 3) which is correct, but then provide indexing in 3 dimensions ([voxel_indices[:, 0], voxel_indices[:, 1], voxel_indices[:, 2]). This would not work like this without some additional transformation.

@Valeria the indexing is of mask_downsampled, which does have three dimensions. Could you try it out, or clarify your problem? Happy to modify my answer if your situation is different than my interpretation.

@Valeria Any progress on this?
